# What is the difference between ByteBuddy's Implementation.Composable and Implementation.Compound?

Tags: byte-buddy

In ByteBuddy, there are seemingly two ways of sequencing `Implementation`s.

Using one way, you can chain them together:

```
// Implementation.Composable; MethodCall "is a" Implementation.Composable; "is a" Implementation
someMethodCall.andThen(someOtherMethodCall)
```

Using another, you can just add them as a list:

```
// Implementation.Compound; "is a" Implementation
new Implementation.Compound(myListOfImplementations)
```

In both cases you end up with a single object that is, itself, an `Implementation`, and so is suitable for supplying to the [`intercept` method](https://javadoc.io/static/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.16/net/bytebuddy/dynamic/DynamicType.Builder.AbstractBase.Adapter.MethodDefinitionAdapter.html#intercept-net.bytebuddy.implementation.Implementation-).

Are they intended to be essentially equal ways of doing the same thing?

I ask the question because I happen to have several `Implementation`s (`MethodCall`s as it happens), and so it seemed to me I could just use the `Implementation.Compound` constructor that takes a list of `Implementation`s.  But I'm also familiar with the `andThen()` method, so I hesitated.

Anyway, when I use the [`Implementation.Compound`](https://javadoc.io/static/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.16/net/bytebuddy/implementation/Implementation.Compound.html) form, if I [add two `MethodCall`s to a new `Implementation.Compound`](https://javadoc.io/static/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.16/net/bytebuddy/implementation/Implementation.Compound.html#Compound-java.util.List-) and then use the resulting `Implementation.Compound` as the argument to an `intercept()` call, I get a bytecode verification error at class load time, complaining about a missing stack frame:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: 
Expecting a stack map frame
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/foo/GeneratedSubclassOf$com$foo$AbstractFactory$26753A95.frob(Lcom/foo/TestFrob$Thing;Ljava/util/List;)V @15: aload_1
  Reason:
    Error exists in the bytecode
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2b2c 03b9 001e 0200 c000 20b8 0024 b12b
    0000010: 2c04 b900 1e02 00c0 0020 b800 27b1
```

Note the trailing four spaces suggesting to my naïve eyes that perhaps something is missing here.  Or perhaps it is some other artifact of my code, but when there is exactly one `Implementation` supplied to a new `Implementation.Compound`, everything works fine.  So I'm thinking that perhaps the `Implementation.Compound` construct is not intended for sequencing `Implementation`s (but then what *is* it intended for)?  Or maybe there is a bug in `Implementation.Compound` (I would think that would be *very* unlikely)?

When I use the (more cumbersome) `Implementation.Composable` construct with the same sub-`Implementation`s, everything works fine.

I'm concerned that I am misinterpreting what each construct is supposed to be used for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `Implementation.Compound` only concatenates two instances without these instances knowing each other. If you compound two implementations that contain:

```
return doSomething();
```

You end up with illegal code:

```
return doSomething();
return doSomething();
```

Using the `andThen` steps of `Implementation.Composable`, the first method assures that it does not return a value but clears it's stack. This way, you end up:

```
doSomething();
return doSomething();
```

Typically, these two adjusted implementations are then combined by an `Implementation.Compound`, but it's important that you inform the first implementation and let it create the compound.